# Reverse voltage protection for TBD62083

Tags: mosfet-driver, reverse-polarity

Good day everybody.
This is my first question on this site so bare with me :) .

I am working on general purpose driver using TBD62083 (replacement of darlington array ULN2803). As you can see the circuit is realy simple:

[image]

The only problem that I foreseen is reversing polarity on POW1 connector.
Analysing the internal diagram of the driver I came with this solution:
[image]

Of course that on 24V the resistor must be rated to at least  5W. I don't have room on PCB for such big resistor so I was also thinking to add a resetable fuse in series with resistor.

So, my questions are:

Will this setup affect in normal operation (in case of using an inductive load) the clamp diode?

Did anyone tried a better solution?

Is this device suitable for paralleling the outputs (no reference found in datasheet)?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for? What's the purpose of 100 ohm resistor and resetable fuses?

Comment: Is it correct that you simply want to add reverse polarity protection to POW1?

Comment: Hi. When you will reverse power supply this circuit via Pow1 connector, the diode that it is tied to ground will start conducting because "COMMON" is tied now to GND. Same for parasitic diode. Because the parasitic diode it is conducting then the clamp diode will conduct as well. If no load on "COMMON" then the device will be destroyed. Now, on 24V with 100 ohms resistor the power on it will be ~5W. I do not have enough room for it so I was thinking to  Adding a small resistor and a polyfuse.

Comment: @hekete Yes it is correct. I know that it can be done with a diode or a P channel mosfet in series but at this moment I cannot use those solutions.

Comment: Can you explain why none of the standard reverse polarity protection methods are suitable for this purpose?

Comment: @hekete Of course :). This is a part of a larger circuit that "should" be able to drive some tiny valves. Some test PCB's were already manufactured and they had to be tested  on site. There is no room on PCB to add a standard reverse protection. So i was thinking to try this one until a new revison will be made.

Comment: Replace the 100 ohm resistor with a diode - why can’t you do that?

Comment: @Andyaka Because the valves are inductive loads. In normal operation the clamp diode will not work.

Comment: Please add these valves/inductive loads into the schematic of your question, and try to answer comments by updating your original question using the "edit" link. That way, people reading your question the first time, directly have all important information.

Comment: Can you replace POW1 connector by a polarized connector? Or wire the diode protecting together with the mating part? The PCB doesn't have room for a standard diode protection, but it has room for this new introduced 100\$ \Omega\$ resistor? Could you please show the PCB as well?

Comment: @Huisman I am afraid that I can not take a picture to pcb, at least at this moment. I wanted to keep the board as "compact" as possible, and it was room for a 1206 footprint resistor. But we decided that it is better to make some cables with crimped ferules and series Schottky diodes at least for a couple of weeks. Thanks everybody.